# Return checked checkbox value outside modal to parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have created two columns, one contains the button and another contains a div, which initially doesn't contain any text. The button will open the modal and a user has various options to choose from and will then select the check box required and the value of the selected checkbox will be displayed on the div. But this code doesn't display the value in the div. I tried various ways but wasn't able to find the solution to the problem.

Below is the code I have written:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnSave').click(function() {
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='check']:checked"), function() {
      favorite.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#demo').html(favorite.join(", "));
    $('#staticBackdrop').modal('hide');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="">
      <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop">Selected parameters </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="editor">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">Selection of parameters</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body fs-6">
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option3
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option4
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option5
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option6
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
              <label><input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="check" id="flexCheckDefault">
                  option7
                </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnSave">Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" id="btnSave">` your btnSave is a submit button - so your entire page gets reloaded *unless* you have something to stop this (not shown in provided code).  So any UI changes in your btnClick will be lost as the page reloads.

Comment: Add a `return false` to your `btnSave` `click` handler so it doesn't submit the form - you *should* then see your page updated - but your form won't submit of course.

Comment: You don't have inputs with name 'check', try `$("input[type='checkbox']:checked")` instead.

Comment: You have duplicated `id`s in DOM, which is illegal markup and likely to yield unwanted page behavior. Either remove the `id` attribute from your `<input>` tags or assign them distinct `id`s. Every single `id` attribute in DOM must be unique across the entire document, at all times.